# MySQL syntax error when executing SQL query

Tags: mysql, jdbc

When I try to run the code below I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1`

```
String query="Select * from DB.Admin where username = ?";
PreparedStatement st=connection.prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(1,request.getParameter("loginid"));
ResultSet rst= st.executeQuery(query);
int count=0;
while(rst.next()){
   count++;
}
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the `query` argument from your `executeQuery` call. If you provide the parameter, the query will be executed without binding any values (see [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) for details) - this is why the syntax (i.e. the `?`) is invalid.

Execute the query like this:

```
ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery();
```

As a side note: you should always wrap `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` with a *try-with-resources* block, e.g.

```
try (ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery()) {
    // read the results
}
```

This way you can be sure the `ResultSet` will be closed no matter what happens.